# ASP.NET connection string

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I have the following asp.net connection string used for my ASP.NET 2.0 application with oracle database.

I don't understand how does it connects to the database since the connection string only specify the server name but not the service name / sid of the database.

How does it works with the Oracle client tnsnames.ora

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name ="someNameHere" connectionString="Server=servername;uid=username;PWD=password;" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Would you please include the connection string?